# massban / massunban commands only work for users within the server. How can I make it so it also bans/unbans users not in the server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have been trying to create two commands — one that bans many users and another that lifts the ban of multiple users;massban and massunban.

These two commands do work for users  that are in the server, the caveat is that it does not work to IDs that are not within the server.

The idea here is to do !massban ID ID ID ID (...) and !massunban ID ID ID ID (...)

```
    @commands.command(name="massban")
    @commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator", "Bot")
    async def massban(self, context, *user_ids: int):
        for u in user_ids:
            user_object = self.client.get_user(u)
            await context.guild.ban(user_object)

    @commands.command(name="massunban")
    @commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator", "Bot")
    async def massunban(self, context, *user_ids: int):
        for u in user_ids:
            user_object = self.client.get_user(u)
            await context.guild.unban(user_object)
```

The problem is that this returns the error which is as follows

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dazz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Dazz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dazz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I have been looking at documents, searching everywhere for a solution for this issue; I asked for help in a few Discord servers but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: It is enabled!

`intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that users aren't automatically loaded in cache. So Discord.py can't get the user from the cache. The solution here is to use `.fetch_user()`. This is an API call which you shouldn't use but you have to in such cases.

So the revised code looks like:

```
@commands.command(name="massban")
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator", "Bot")
async def massban(self, context, *user_ids: int):
    for u in user_ids:
        user_object = await self.client.fetch_user(u)
        await context.guild.ban(user_object)

@commands.command(name="massunban")
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator", "Bot")
async def massunban(self, context, *user_ids: int):
    for u in user_ids:
        user_object = await self.client.fetch_user(u)
        await context.guild.unban(user_object)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also added await next to `self.client.fetch_user(u)` so it would fix `enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback` error! It would look like this `user_object = await self.client.fetch_user(u)`

Comment: Oh, right, always forget that await xD You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

To add into FlexGames answer. In version **1.6**, discord.py `UserConverter` already fetches the Users given if you gave an ID and checks if the ID is valid. The answer can be shortened. UserConverter also accepts name/mentions/ID which is a bonus. It's stated here [UserConverter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.UserConverter)

**Here's the compact version**

```py
@commands.command(name="massban")
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator", "Bot")
async def massban(self, ctx, *users: discord.User):
    # map calls ctx.guild.ban for each users
    # asyncio.gather awaits each coroutine concurrently
    await asyncio.gather(*map(ctx.guild.ban, users))

@commands.command(name="massunban")
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator", "Bot")
async def massunban(self, ctx, *users: discord.User):
    await asyncio.gather(*map(ctx.guild.unban, users))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing that method too! Upvoted.